# get object from firebase database ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

i'm having trouble when i want to get data from the firebase database.

**user-service.ts**

```js
  getProfile(){
    try {;
      return this.afDatabse.object(`profile/${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      
    }
  }
```

**contact.ts**

```js
  async ionViewWillLoad(){
      const result = await this.userService.getProfile();
      console.log(result);
      
  }
```

[image]

I don't know why i'm having this response but not my profile object

Comment: You would need to convert the Firebase observable into a promise. Try `Observable.prototype.toPromise`

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm trying but not working for the moment. i will be back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  this.afDatabse.object(`profile/${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  })
```

Try tapping on .valueChanges() to the object. I had the same issue for a few hours and stumbled across [update notes](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md) on the angularfire2 repo.